# Representing a fixed number of repeating, independent objects in SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to represent an object with four independent points (and a variety of other properties, represented here by [...]) in SQL. A single table approach might look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Object (
    Id bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [...]
    Point1X float NOT NULL,
    Point1Y float NOT NULL,
    Point2X float NOT NULL,
    Point2Y float NOT NULL,
    Point3X float NOT NULL,
    Point3Y float NOT NULL,
    Point4X float NOT NULL,
    Point4Y float NOT NULL
)
```

Where a multi-table approach might look more like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Object (
    Id bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [...]
    Point1 bigint NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Point(Id),
    Point2 bigint NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Point(Id),
    Point3 bigint NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Point(Id),
    Point4 bigint NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Point(Id)
)

CREATE TABLE Point (
    Id bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    XCoord float NOT NULL,
    YCoord float NOT NULL
)
```

The second approach looks far more elegant coming from an OO design background, but at the same time I can already see how it will be a bit more difficult to work with when updating the objects in question inside my ORM and I don't like the number of FK constraints I'm adding. The first option looks very cluttered, and it also means that I will not be able to add other properties to the points after the fact (say, if I wanted to assign a `Color` to each point in six month's time).

I would also say that there's a third option, where the `Points` table maintains a foreign key reference back to the `Object`, which means that an object may now have any number of points. I don't like this option as much. For the current scope of the project an object will only ever have exactly four points, so that constraint would then have to be dealt with on my application layer, and it makes dealing with the relation inside the ORM even more difficult.

What's the correct way to work out a design like this?

---

EDIT: A few more details:

- Points are representing the midpoint of each side of a rectangle - imagine a cross-like shape.
- It's important to know which points are across from each other - hence having a center defined, or having some kind of ordering (point1 is always directly across from point3, for instance).
- Aside from the above constraint, there is no ordering of points.
- At the moment I will only be querying for objects and then drawing their points, not running queries against the points themselves, although I could see this being a requirement in the future.
- Objects shouldn't overlap, but this isn't a hard constraint in the system.
- Objects likewise shouldn't share the same four points. Since the points are floats (at least, in this example - I'm open to better suggestions for datatypes) and are originally taken from user input (think mouse cursor positions on a canvas) I don't think it's very likely that any two objects will ever share *any* points.

Comment: I don't think you've provided enough requirements to determine the optimal design. For instance:

What kind of queries do you expect to issue against the database? Design #1 gets awkward if you are looking to return all objects that have a point within a given range. 

Are the points ordered? 

Are there unique constraint that revolve around the points? Can 2 objects overlap? Or have the same 4 points?

Comment: @Aheho I've added some extra details to answer your questions. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more opinion that a statement of the right way to model this problem.

You have 3 potential designs. I'll call them

1. Single Table
2. Two Table
3. Three table (Matt's answer).

The key factors, in my mind are:

- Will there be a need to generalize relationship between objects and points to a 1 to N relationship? Will the relationship always be 1 to 4?
- Will there be a need to work with points outside the context of objects? Such as the need to query all points within a given range?

If the answer to those 2 questions are no/no, then I would go with solution 1, and leave the compositional model in the OO space, giving the OO/DB mapping layer the task of decomposing the object graph into 1 row in 1 table. Yes the column defs don't look elegant, but once the table is in place everything should be easier to work with. No Joins. No FKs. No potential to accidentally create an object with only 2 points. You will likely get the best performance with this solution as well.

If the answer to either of the above questions is yes, I would choose option #3, although I think the association table needs another field to specify how a point relates to the object (i.e. Point #1/#3 or Point #2/#4). No doubt Matt was unaware of that requirement when he crafted his answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an uncommon design decision.

Between your two approaches, I prefer the second.  The reason is simple.  If you have four of "something" then that "something" sounds like an entity.  In a relational model, an entity should have its own table.

However, you reject my actual preferred option, which is to have a foreign key reference back to the original objects.  The only issue is enforcing the number constraint.  You can do that by using a trigger to maintain the count and rejecting any attempt to insert a fifth point.  I am not thrilled with the need to use a trigger, but SQL isn't always powerful enough to represent everything we want to represent directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Object (
    Id bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [...]
)

CREATE TABLE Point (
    Id bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    XCoord float NOT NULL,
    YCoord float NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE ObjectPointCrossRef (
    Id bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ,ObjectId bigint NOT NULL
    ,PointId bigint NOT NULL
)
```

I understand this structure isn't as nice from an application programming standpoint but as far as a data standpoint and flexibility to accommodate application requirement changes it works nicely.  Also if you commonly share points between objects this might lead to a space savings because multiple objects can reference the same point...  Take the example of now needing 5 points (pentagon) no programming changes are needed [I know you said that won't happen but I can only assume you are allowing rectangles of some kind....  Or perhaps adding a color to only 1 objects point add a color to the Cross Reference table.